# Python Selenium: unable to reach particular image in a flyer to scrape text

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape this website: https://www.longos.com/flyers.

I've been able to enter the postal code (ex.M5B 0B7 for people who may not be familiar with postal codes in this area) , click on the closest store and have the flyer pop up.

However, I am having troubles clicking into the specific flyer page, get the particular product and get the text information. The code below is my attempt.

```
i = 1
while True:
    flyer_link = "/html/body/flipp-router/flipp-publication-page/div/flipp-sfml-component/sfml-storefront/div/sfml-linear-layout/sfml-flyer-image[{}]".format(i)
    print(flyer_link)
    flyer = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, flyer_link)))
    print(flyer)


    i+=1
```

It doesn't seem to be abble to recognize the XPATH

Here is a snapshot of the html code for reference:
[image]

```
j = 1

for i in prdcts:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", i)
    i.click()
time.sleep(3)
print(i)
# print(driver.page_source)

i = 1
while True:

    try:
        button_link_to_text = '/html/body/flipp-router/flipp-publication-page/div/flipp-sfml-component/sfml-storefront/div/sfml-linear-layout/sfml-flyer-image[{}]/div/button[{}]'.format(j,i)
        button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(button_link_to_text)
        print(button.get_attribute("aria-label"))
        i+=1
    except:
        break
j+=1
```

Comment: The website says access denied. So, could you paste the html code instead of the image. Also, make sure to paste the html code above the flyer too, as we may need to traverse from its parent. Also, check if the flyer exists inside of an iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.longos.com/flyers')
time.sleep(5)

iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@class="flippiframe productframe"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
eleme = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="postal-input"]')
eleme.send_keys("M5B0B7")
eleme = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@id="submit-postal-code"]').click()
time.sleep(2)
eleme = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button [@aria-label="Select Elizabeth 111 Elizabeth Street Toronto ON, distance from store is <1 km"]').click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
time.sleep(5)
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@class="flippiframe mainframe"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
prdcts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//sfml-flyer-image//button')
print (prdcts)
for i in prdcts:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", i)
    print(i.get_attribute("aria-label"))
    
    time.sleep(3)
    print(I)
```

and don't forget to switch back to `class="flippiframe productframe"]` this frame to get the product details.

the main thing is you need to **switch the iframes and get into view** to interact with that element

Comment: Awesome that worked! However when I tried to go into the frame to get the text, it doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: Did you switched backed to the default content ? And then go to  product frame ??.. switching back to default is important.

Comment: I added some additional code and was able to get the text but the code seems to keep running. I've posted the code in the edited version of this question.

Comment: I think it is because this link of code: prdcts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//sfml-flyer-image//button') is fetching a lot more information than expected

Comment: check the updated code

Comment: Thanks, this is working like I wanted. Thank you so much. In addition, I wonder if it is possible to click on a product and get some "description" related to the product. I noticed the aria-label only captures the basic info such as the name and price.

Comment: yes, first I thought that was your initial thought. In that case you need to switch between the iframes

Comment: Okay. I just tried that but it doesn't seem to be recognizing when I try to switch to the iframe similarly to how you have had done it